# Perforce - Delete files and history from a Stream(Permission issue)

Tags: perforce, p4v

I'm trying to delete the files and history from a Stream
I tried "p4 obliterate" command, but it says "you don't have permission for this operation" but I create this stream and also I'm the only user and also the super user , show by [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEL0K.jpg)  , So my QUESTION is why and how can delete the stream , thanks . I know people say not recommend to NOT DO THIS.I have my own reason so don't worry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prior to running "p4 obliterate", run "p4 info" and check what it says your user name is.

If it does not say "kitman.yiu", do:

```
p4 set P4USER=kitman.yiu
```

and try again.

Comment: thanks it done. but this time shows me no records to delete any idea?

Comment: Sounds like you may have typed the wrong path?  Try running "p4 files" on the same path and see if there's anything actually there.  Also make sure you're connected to the right server, etc.